# Make container DIV cover 100% of containing DIV's height

Tags: css, html, height

I'm working on a new website and on [one my pages](http://www.ht-webcreations.com/aloro/layout-02.php) I just cant get my #main div which is my page content's containing DIV to stretch long enough to cover the inner DIV's.

Please check it out and point out the parts of my CSS that need fixing. Many thanks to all.

Comment: bikey77 - Can you post the pertinent code here in the question so that it's useful to everyone?

Answer (score 2):

@bikey; just right

```
#main {
    background: none repeat scroll 0 0 #101010;
    border-color: #333333;
    border-style: solid;
    border-width: 1px 1px 0;
    margin: 15px auto 0;
    overflow: hidden;
    padding: 20px;
    width: 920px;
}
```

The problem is in your `#main div` there are `floated` element's so you have to clear it first.
in the example above i write `overflow:hidden` & remove `height:100%`

Answer (score 1):

Just remove `height: 100%` from layout.css at `#main{...}` (line 31 or so) 
and add `<br style="clear:both;" />` after `<div id="content">...</div>`